# c# using multiple listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem, operation

I have 2 ListBoxes and 2 TextBoxes, what I need it to do is if I click an item in list box 1 it shows 2 or more items in list box 2 and if I click an item in list box 2 there will be an operation and it will appear in text box 1 and text box 2,
ex. ballpen=10,notebook=20

The items included in "listBox1" are the "pen" and "notebook". If I click notebook an item will show in list box 2: 1,2 then if I click "1", text box 1.text=20 because notebook is 20*1=20

Comment: What you are looking for is the event called SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: can u please give me some example using selectedindexchanged. tnx! :D

Comment: Google is your friend. There are millions of examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm just going to create an enumeration for your items.

```
public enum ListBoxItemThing
{
    Pen = 10, Notebook = 20
}
```

And then I'll add these to "listBox1" inside the form constructor.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach(ListBoxItemThing item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ListBoxItemThing)))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

And then use this procedure to do the calculation for textBox1:

```
private void Calculate()
{
    int a = (int)(listBox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItemThing);
    int b = int.Parse(listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
    textBox1.Text = (a * b).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a dictionary stores information of listBox1 and listBox2. key is an item in listBox1, value is list items in listBox2. when you click an item in listBox1 => call SelectedIndexChanged event of listBox1 => get item you selected(assume = value1) => looking for in dictionary with key = value1 => you will get list items in listBox2(assume = listItems) => add listItems into listBox2 => when you click an item in listBox2 call SelectedIndexChanged event of listBox2 => update value for textbox1 and textbox2 = items was selected in listBox1 and listBox2.